# Snort Ping test only works when snort server is involved

Tags: linux, ubuntu, snort

Noob alert!! I have installed snort on one server 'a'. I have two more servers b and c on the same network. I have created a test icmp rule

```
`alert icmp any any -> $HOME_NET any (msg:"ICMP test detected"; GID:1;sid:10000001; rev:001; classtype:icmp-event;)`
```

(yeah, straight out of the document). 
Anyway, it seems to be working correctly, but only when snort server is involved. Please see the below cases and results
ping a to b works

ping a to c works

ping b to a works

ping c to a works

local to a works

however:

ping local to b doesn't work

ping local to c doesn't work

ping b to c doesn't work

How do I know if snort is working correctly? Is the rule supposed to generate this type of result?

I have setup HOME_NET variable to x.x.0.0/16.

Comment: Snort is network ids. To monitor all network by snort, you must copy all network traffic to snort. Or you must make snort to gateway. https://openmaniak.com/snort_other.php

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. right now implementing on Azure and Azure network watcher looks promising. Anyway thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Will let you know how it goes

Answer (score 0):

Check the responses over here [Snort not detecting Pings with other devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59950060/snort-not-detecting-pings-with-other-devices/65210526#65210526)

I think it is what you're looking for