# Snort not detecting Pings with other devices

Tags: system, detection, rules, snort, ids

I have a problem with Snort, I've just installed the program on a R-Pi. 2 other computers on the same network can ping the R-Pi with success.

However I had the idea that snort was able to be run in Promiscuous mode meaning that it can see all traffic in a local network... without needing to run it inline in the network.
When i try ping the other two computers in the same network Snort does not pick this up.

**Changes** i have tried....

Ruleset set to -

```
alert icmp any any -> any any
```

Config file set to -

```
ipvar HOME_NET 192.168.43.0/32 (<this is my home network range)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a virtual machine, make sure that your network configuration is setup as **bridged adapter** and **promiscuous mode** is enabled in your virtual machine with snort.

I'm using virtual box and this is how it looks like:

[image: network config]

Answer (score 0):

Does Snort start up correctly? If the whole rule is given in the question, then perhaps the SID for it was not indicated.

You can try:

```
alert tcp any any -> any any (msg: "Just a test alert"; sid:1000001;)
```